# force Static IP on VM creation

Tags: ansible, centos7, vmware

I have an ansible script that connects to my Vcenter and builds out a VM.  This works great assuming the network it will be built on has DHCP enabled.  I am building mostly Centos 7 VM's on a network that does not have DHCP enabled meaning static IP's.  The VM gets built, but then I am stuck logging into each VM manually and assigning the IP.

How can I tell CentOS to use a specific IP?

I am familiar with kickstart, but not sure how to trigger the install to pickup a ks file.  (I know I can create a custom ISO, but I dont want to create a custom ISO for each VM I built.)
I have tried using the following flags on ansible VMware_guest module, but no luck.

Any Suggestions??

```
vmware_guest:
    network:
      type: static
      ip: 192.168.1.5
      mask: 255.255.255.0
      gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Do you get any error

Comment: Your question got nothing common with netiher ansible, nor vmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using netmask instead of mask.

```
vmware_guest:
    network:
      name: "{{ network_name }}"
      type: static
      ip: 192.168.1.5
      netmask: 255.255.255.0
      gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: That does not work either.  I dont get any errors.  The VM gets created but with DHCP enabled.  I need a way to assign it a static IP upon creation, so basically overwrite the kickstart file.

Comment: which version of ansible? I saw a github issue closed with comment as.This issue is fully working with Ansible 2.7.7. Please check https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/38715

Comment: I am running 3.7.5.  YES this issue got fixed on a Windows VM, there is no mention about a Linux (CentOS) VM.